# How Would I Create Dynamic Sub-Arrays In JavaScript And Add Separate Values To Them?

Tags: javascript, node.js

To be specific, I need to be able to essentially store, modify, and read values written in the arrays. For example:

```
var regusers = new Array();

if (regusers[id].registered == false) // id is set as the static ID from the user (F.E. 52250b3c877b9254c9eb6c4a)
{
    regusers[id].registered = true;
}
```

I apologize in advanced if my question is either not descriptive enough or is a duplicate. But in truth, I can't find another question quite like it. I'm just having a very frustrating time with this and need some help... Thank you community for helping!

P.S. I may have worded the title incorrectly? I will change it if someone explains. Thank you again for the help. It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var regusers = {'52250b3c877b9254c9eb6c4a':{registered:false}};

for(var id in regusers){
    if(regusers[id].registered==false){
        regusers[id].registered = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want an associative array (an object in javascript), that contains objects. Here is a sample data that would work with your code:

```
var regusers = {};
regusers['52250b3c877b9254c9eb6c4a'] = {
    registered: false
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you a value if the `id` was found and `undefined` if not

```
var id = '52250b3c877b9254c9eb6c4a';

var regusers = [{'52250b3c877b9254c9eb6c4a':'value 1'},
                {'120b3c877b9254c9eb6c4a':'value 2'}];

 for(var i in regusers){
     for(var x in regusers[i]){        
         console.log(regusers[i][id]);
      }
  }
```

you can validate on the `typeof` undefined

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/gH25C/)